# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm creating a React Calendar App using Firebase, and I'm having some problems with printing the Date for each event scheduled.

Here is my App code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input } from '@material-ui/core';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

import db from './firebase'
import TodoList from './TodoList'



const HomePage = () => {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('todos').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setTodos(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, todo: doc.data().todo, date: doc.data().date })))
    })
  }, [])

  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    db.collection('todos').add({
      todo: input,
      date: startDate,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })

    setTodos([...todos, input, startDate ])
    setInput('')
  }


  return (
    <div className='text-center' >
      <h1>TO DO LIST FIREBASE</h1>
      <form onSubmit={addTodo}>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>Write Your Todo</InputLabel>
          <Input value={input} onChange={event => setInput(event.target.value)} />
          <DatePicker selected={startDate} 
                      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} 
                      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
                      showTimeSelect 
          />
          <Button disabled={!input} variant='contained' color='primary' type='submit' >
            Add Todo
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </form>

      <TodoList todos={todos} />
    </div >
  )
}



export default HomePage;
```

And here is my Todo List component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import db from './firebase';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import { List } from '@material-ui/core'


export default function TodoList( { todos }) {
    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {todo.todo}
                        <br />
                        {todo.date}
                        <DeleteIcon onClick={event => db.collection('todos').doc(todo.id).delete()} />
                    </li>

                ))}
            </List>
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem is... I can only pass the "date" as a String in Seconds... And when I try to convert it on my Todo List component to return it as human readable date, it brings me this error.

EDIT:
Here is a print of what I have:
[TodoList with seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek7WC.png)

And I would like to change it to a normal Date format without getting this error.

Comment: Is this your real code? Because this looks wrong in a different way to what you're describing: `setTodos([...todos, input, startDate ])`

Comment: This is just an MVP, but can you explain me why it looks wrong?

Comment: You're adding a string and date as element values in the `todos` array, not adding a new object with `todo` and `date` properties to it. An [mcve] must be accurate to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's cuz your `todo.date`'s type is Object.

for example

```
const date = new Date(timeStamp)

// in jsx
{date }
// u will got error : Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

// convert it to primitive type
{data.toLocaleString()}
```

or u can try this way

```
<DatePicker selected={startDate} 
                      onChange={date => setStartDate(new Date(date).toLocaleString())} 
                      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
                      showTimeSelect 
          />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand... the question is: How can I change it to Human Date without getting that error

Comment: u can try `new Date(timeStamp).toDateString()` or `new Date(timeStamp).toLocaleString()` or u can use moment.js to handle this problem

Comment: The problem is... When I try to convert it in my component's child, it throws me the error. Becaus `new Date()` can't be used....

Answer (score 1):

When I used:

```
todo.date.toLocaleString()
```

it showed:

```
Timestamp(seconds=1623991287, nanoseconds=689000000)
```

Not a MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS type string.

So I used this:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
    }).format(todo.date.seconds * 1000);
```

and it worked

```
 01/08/1972, 02:59:48 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Objects are invalid in React.js. You'll need to use string format of the date like:

```
{todo.date.toLocaleString()}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I've done this code, but it returns only seconds and when I try to change it to Human Date, it gives me that error again. My question is... how can I return a Human Date instead of this Timestamp?

Comment: Using `toTimeString()`?